# I'm trying to calculate pi in python3 using infinite loops:

Tags: python-3.x, infinite-loop, pi

```
answer=0
for i in range (11):
    k=i
    x = (-1**k) / ((2 * k) + 1)
    answer+=x
answer=4*answer
print(answer)
```

output: -8.723498311114408

it should be close to 3.14

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact, which could at least partially explain your situation.  The other issue could be that the formula is wrong.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, because I can't test rn, but I think it should be (-1)**k. Also you want the variable to be named `k` just change the loop to `for k in range(11)` instead of reassigning

Comment: @user8408080 that is the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`**` has precedence over `-` (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)), hence `-1 ** k` evalutes to `-(1 ** k)` which is of course not what you meant.

Change `x = (-1 ** k) / ((2 * k) + 1)` to `x = (-1) ** k / ((2 * k) + 1)`